# How to get object URL of all image files from multiple folders in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]I have multiple subfolders for many files.

Total # of subfolders denoted as "Box" (FOLDER_1) = 24

Total # of subfolders within FOLDER_1 (FOLDER_2) = 1505

S3 object URL are of the format:

> [https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER_1/FOLDER_2](https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER_1/FOLDER_2)

Found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826882/get-object-url-of-s3-all-s3-files-in-a-folder); however, I am experiencing issues when looping an array.

Here is the code:

```
import boto3

s3_uri="s3://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER_1/FOLDER2/" # S3 URI of the folder you want to recursively scan, Replace this with your own S3 URI

# Split the s3 uri to extract bucket name and the file prefix
# Splitting S3 URI will generate an array
# Combine the appropirate elements of the array to extraxt BUCKET_NAME and PREFIX
arr=s3_uri.split('/')
bucket =arr[2]
prefix=""
for i in range(3,len(arr)-1):
    prefix=prefix+arr[i]+"/"
    
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

def list_s3_files_using_client(bucket,prefix,s3_client):
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket,  Prefix=prefix) # Featch Meta-data of all the files in the folder
    files = response.get("Contents")
    for file in files: # Iterate through each files
        file_path=file['Key']
        object_url="https://"+bucket+".s3.amazonaws.com/"+file_path #create Object URL  Manually
        print("Object Url =  "+object_url)

list_s3_files_using_client(bucket=bucket,prefix=prefix,s3_client=s3_client)
```

Example of desired output:

```
https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER_1/FOLDER_1/FILE_NAME_1
https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER_1/FOLDER_2/FILE_NAME_1
https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER_2/FOLDER_3/FILE_NAME_1
.
.
.
https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER_N/FOLDER_N/FILE_NAME_N
```

Comment: You say "I am experiencing issues when looping an array". Please tell us what 'issues' you are experiencing. Does the code work?

Comment: Why did you circle the number `1` in your screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided works perfectly well.

A simplified version is:

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
PREFIX = 'LPs & 12s/'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET, Prefix=PREFIX)
for object in response['Contents']:
    print(f"https://{BUCKET}/{object['Key']}")
```

You do not explain what 'issues' you are having, but I notice that you have a sub-directory called `LPs & 12s`, which **might cause problems in a URL** due to the space and the `&`.

To 'fix' the bad characters, you can use `urllib.parse.quote()` to replace characters with escape codes.

It will change this:

```
https://my-bucket/LPs & 12s/Box 1/1.108.1-AL 9530
```

into:

```
https://my-bucket/LPs%20%26%2012s/Box%201/1.108.1-AL%209530
```

Here is the updated code:

```py
for object in response['Contents']:
    safe_key = quote(object['Key'])
    print(f"https://{BUCKET}/{safe_key}")
```